# Get HitTestResult for arbitrary point

Tags: android, android-webview, hittest

I'd like to be able to figure out what object is at an arbitrary (x,y) point in a `WebView`, preferably without causing anything to change on the page. I'm developing an accessibility app for Android where the target of a link needs to be identified before the link is activated; long-pressing on the link is (sadly) not an option.

`getHitTestResult` does basically what I want, but only for the current "cursor node". I can't find any documentation about this "cursor node", but I suspect it requires a touch event to appear at the target point.

Answer (score 0):

*Not a way to find the node element from a point*, but if you want to override a link clicked event fonctionnality on a webview you can do this :

add a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to you web view using setWebViewClient method.
Then override the [shouldOverrideUrlLoading()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method and check given target **url**

hint : if it returns true, the url won't be loaded since it means that your native app is handling it.

code sample :

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              if (isUrlGood(url))
                  return false; //the webview can load the url
              else
                  return true; //avoid the webview from loading this url
         }
 });
```

Comment: I need to identify the target of the link *before* the link is activated.

Comment: do you mean before it has been clicked ? That is more a javascript problem, implement it in javascript and make a little communication between the webview and the java code to recover it ...